# WooCommerce Wordpress can't find total order after checkout/pyament

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, woocommerce, checkout

I use a custom payment, which I display in an iframe and pass on variables into a form.

I need to pass the total order without currency sign after checkout/payment.

I've found a way to pass the cart total before checkout/payment using

```
echo WC()->cart->total
```

On the checkout after payment page (`thankyou.php`) I've found

```
echo $order->get_formatted_order_total();
```

This will display the total order with a currency sign only on the `thankyou.php` page and will not pass onto any other page no matter what i tried (which isn't important as I can work with ether thankyou.php page or actual checkout page)

Full code looks like this inside a list

```
            <?php _e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?>
```

I've tried testing to see how wordpress stores order total both on thankyou.php page and on a seperate page to see if I can call the order total from the array after checkout/payment but I ether get a value of 0.00 or my page breaks

Code I tried so far:

```
echo $order->get_order_total();
```

this breaks the page

```
echo WC()->$order->get_order_total();
```

this breaks the page

```
echo $order->get_total();
```

this also breaks the page

calling total cart `echo WC()->cart->total` after checkout/payment will display 0 (which makes sense)

Comment: When you say `echo $order->get_total();` **breaks the page**, what error is displayed? If NO error, be sure to edit your `wp-config` file and turn `WP_DEBUG` to `TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

If it's the thank you page, then it's simple enough - you just need to use this and it should work without breaking the page.

In your `templates/checkout/thankyou.php` file, add this code:

```
if ( ! $order) {
    echo 'No order object!';
} else if ($order->has_status( 'failed' ) {
    echo 'Order failed for some reason.';
} else {
    echo $order->get_total();
}
```

If you don't have the `$order` object, you can get it from the order id:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order->get_total();
```

If you don't have the order id OR the `$order` object available, then we need more information to be able to help.

Comment: Thank you very much
Found similar solution and came back to post it here for documentation and sharing of information.